# IE8 & 9 Security Issue with jquery AJAX "Cross Domain" request

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I have a jQuery AJAX request which works perfectly in Chrome & Firefox. The code doesn't work in IE 8/9. I've determined it to be an issue with IE Security settings, specifically the "access data sources across domains" option. If I set this to Yes (default no), everything works fine! The only issue is that, it's NOT a cross domain request! Here's the relevant code.

```
 $.ajax({                                    
 url: 'dophp.php?make='+ thisValue, data: '', dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
 {
```

Am i missing something? How does this get thrown in with cross domain requests? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: put crossdomain.xml in your site

Comment: but this isn't flash content? Through java you would do a Access-Control-Allow-Origin:, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do couple of things, crossdomain.xml well they didn't work well for me, there is HTML Header for it, I didn't remember, but the easiest thing I remember is to use getJSON method of Jquery or using JSONP, JSONP request are independent in these sense and works well for me thus far.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for me! EDIT: Scratch that, cross domain settings were on...the getJSON returns the same issue.